# select price having max year in another column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following select result

Code  Price  Year
1             200    2013
1             100    2012
2             250    2011
2             275    2012
2             300    2010

But I want following something like this with one extra column which hold price based on maximum year,

Code  Price  Year  ExPrice
1             200     2013     200
1             100     2012     200
2             250     2011     275
2             275     2012    275
2             300     2010     275

Sorry for bad English and wrong way for asking this question.

Comment: I can't see any rule here :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `cross apply` and `select top 1 ... order by`:

```
select Code, Price, Year, ExPrice
from TableName T
    cross apply (
        select top 1 Price
        from TableName
        where Code = T.Code
        order by Year desc
    ) p(ExPrice)
```

or `row_number` and `join` (whatever you prefer):

```
;with cte as (
    select Code, Price as ExPrice, rn = row_number() over (partition by Code order by Year desc)
    from TableName
)
select T.Code, Price, Year, ExPrice
from TableName T
    join cte on cte.Code = T.Code and cte.rn = 1
```

[**SQLFiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74672/1)

Comment: Cross apply is better for me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT T1.Code, T1.Price, T1.Year, T2.Price
FROM Table T1
INNER JOIN Table T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code AND
    T2.Year = (SELECT MAX(Year) FROM Table WHERE Table.Code = T2.Code)
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the the max price, but the price of the max year.

Comment: I don't want max price , i want price based on max year.

Comment: @user2703597: Oops, I misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer, so that it should give you what you want :-)

Comment: This looks like it will work as far as selecting the values he wants, as long as the two tables are already created. He would need to insert them into his new table.